# When app crash that time device is not connected to xcode. then how to check crash log?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new in iOS developing,

When QA(testing) person check my app that time device is not connected with xcode. That time the app crashed.

Is it possible to check crash log of my app(with proper format like we see in xcode console).

Like in Android, When Android app crash after you connect device to android studio then android studio provide recent crash in log console.

Please help me. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Crashlytics in your app and run. When any crash happening in live or QA testing. You got the crash log on the dashboard.

Check this: https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install

Comment: this is working for me. but I want to know crash logs in xcode like in Android studio. When Android app crash after you connect device to android studio then android studio provide recent crash in log console. Any way thanks @Faysal for suggest me **Fabric**

Comment: Not like that. Crash log automatically moved to your fabric dashboard. You can easily find the crash log based on version. showing the log its very easy to find the affected area.